# ckeditor image contextual toolbar scrolling up on click

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Ck-editor image contextual toolbar scrolling up on click, when Im uploading some picture and want to manipulate(right, left) toolbar is closing and scrolling up, how to find the issue ?

Im using ck-editor classic editor (super.bundle)